# How to set object at a specific depth from the camera, at a certain pixel

Tags: objects, camera, coordinates, world, depth-map

I want to set an object at a certain distance (or depth) relative to the camera; and also at a particular pixel.

Example:

I set up a camera at a random position in blender. I want an 1280x720 image. So if a line came out of the camera at pixel e.g. (400,400), perpendicular to the image plane; and that line travels 1300 millimeters. It will end up at position (x,y,z) in the blender world. That is the point where I want the bottom centre of my object to be at. How do I calculate this location (x,y,z) ?

[image]

---

*Some more context here. I have a image of a scene with a table. I also have the corresponding depth image, which stores for each pixel, the distance in millimeter from the scene to the camera. I have the segmentation mask of this table. So I know for each point on the table, its distance to the camera. I want to set an object on this table, by rendering the scene as background, and rendering the object on top of it at the correct location from the camera.*

Comment: I guess you are actually searching for a techinque on matching perspective from the photo with rendered image from camera which is done with fSpy addon as of 2.8+. See e.g https://gumroad.com/l/fSpyTute for explanation.

Comment: @MrZak Thanks, but this only aligns the camera position/rotation with that of my picture. (I am not sure this is better than a random camera position with the image as background; in any case, I also have my camera parameters already.) Then I still need to figure out how to set an object a certain depth from that camera.

Comment: you need a camera matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix in blender https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/what-is-blenders-camera-projection-matrix-model **and** https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera  **and**  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108938/how-to-interpret-the-camera-world-matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the [Inverse Projection Transformation](https://towardsdatascience.com/inverse-projection-transformation-c866ccedef1c) or back-projection: 2D pixel -> 3D world coordinate. I only needed the 3D world coordinate relative to the camera. This worked for me:

1. Set up the camera at location (0, 0, 0) and rotation (90, 0, 0) (degrees) with the correct focal length and sensor size.
2. Get the camera intrinsics *Fx*, *Fy* (focal lengths for x and y) and *Cx*, *Cy* (optical centre)
3. Do the back-projection. Here (*Px*, *Py*) is your pixel-coordinate; *Z* is the depth at that pixel-coordinate (received from the depth map I have).

`x = (px - cx) * z / fx`

`y = (py - cy) * z / fy`

Your world coordinate is then (x, y, z) relative to the camera. So with my camera setup, I can set the object at location (x, z, -y) (divided by 1000, because I used millimeter as measurement for the depth).

Answer (score 0):

I think, next must be works:

Sets empty objects to every corner of image - `pinLT, pinRT, pin_BL, pinBR`. Then calculate rays from camera base to those pins:

```
eye = camera.matrix_world @ Vector((0,0,0))
rayLT =  (pinLT.location @ pinLT.matrix_world) - eye
rayRT =  (pinRT.location @ pinRT.matrix_world) - eye
rayLB =  (pinLT.location @ pinLB.matrix_world) - eye
#rayRB =  (pinRT.location @ pinRB.matrix_world) - eye
```

then make interpolation to find correspond ray to the pixel

```
h = (rayRT - rayLT) * pixels.x / pixels.wide
v = (rayLB - rayLT) * pixels.y / pixels.height

ray = pinLT + v + h

# calc result in world coorinates
resultOnImage = eye + ray
resultInWorld = resultOnImage + ray.normalized() * desired_distance
```